# How to match two strings using the position of a character in this string

Tags: php, mysql

I am developing a website where students get to pick a tutor for extra lessons in a specific subject at a specific hour.

**The user states two things:**

- the subjects they want lessons for
- the hours at which they are able to receive the lessons

The school has a total of 24 subjects. And an average school week consists of 5 days, each one having 6 classes, hours. Meaning 30 hours in total.

**So, 24 subjects and 30 hours to choose from.**

After some thinking, I thought that saving the subjects and hours from a student in two separate strings would be the best way to store the information.

For example, in the string subjects. A 1 would represent a subject chosen, and a 0 one that is not chosen. For example: **111100000000000000000000** is possible, the student only chose the first four subjects. The same case for the string hours, a 1 represents an hours chosen, a 0 one that is not.

**So, I got two strings:**

- one called subjects with a length of 24 characters, numbers.
- one called hours with a length of 30 characters, numbers.

Now, of course the students need tutors to choose from. The subjects and hours these tutors teach are stored in a database. Subjects and hours, again, stored in a long string with a length of 24 or 30.

**So, I got two tables in my database:**

- one called subjects, type varchar with a length of 24 characters, numbers.
- one called hours, type varchar with a length of 30 characters, numbers.

Now comes the "hard" part, I can't think of an **efficient** way to match a student with a tutor.

I've been working on a solution, but I don't think it would be the best one.

---

First, I'd store both the input from `subjects` and `hours` from the student:

```
$subjects = $_POST["subjects"];
$hours = $_POST["hours"];
```

Then I'd make sure there aren't any weird characters in there:

```
$subjects = stripslashes($subjects);
$hours = stripslashes($hours);
$subjects = $mysqli->real_escape_string($subjects);
$hours = $mysqli->real_escape_string($hours);
```

Next thing is a bit more complicated. First, I split the string subjects into an array. Next, I compare this array to an array which has 24 numbers of `1`. Doing so, I know the position of the `1's` located in the string `subjects` the student stated:

```
$subjects = str_split($subjects);

$fullsubjects = array(1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1);
$subjectsresult = array_intersect_assoc($subjects, $fullsubjects);
$subjectskeyresult = array_keys($subjectsresult);
```

Knowing the position of the `1's`, I can use this number to select the tutors in the database which also have a `1` at the same position. I then push these users in an array, and order them by the ones that match the most `1's`:

```
$usersubjectsmatch = array();

foreach($subjectskeyresult as $val) {
    $nval = 23 - $val;
    $fullval = str_repeat("_", $val) . 1 . str_repeat("_", $nval);
    $userdataquery = "SELECT firstname FROM members WHERE subjects LIKE '$fullval'";
    $userdataresult = $mysqli->query($userdataquery) or die($mysqli->error);
    $userdataarray = $userdataresult->fetch_assoc();
    $usersubjects = $userdataarray["firstname"];
    array_push($usersubjectsmatch, $usersubjects);
}

$ac = array_count_values($usersubjectsmatch);
arsort($ac);
$ordereduserssubject = array_keys($ac);
print_r($ordereduserssubject);
```

So, this would output a bunch tutors, ordered by most matching, to least matching. The next step would be finding the position of the `1's` in the hours stated by the student and selecting which one of the previously selected tutors also have a `1` at the same position in their hours string.

**But**, again, I don't think this is a proper solution. I was wondering if any of you out there can find a better, more efficient one.

**Also, I'm using AJAX to retrieve the tutors for the students. But providing this script is not necessary.**

PS: Sorry for the title, couldn't think of proper one that describes my problem.

Comment: If the JavaScript client-side is irrelevant, don't tag JavaScript, jQuery, and preferably not AJAX as well.

Comment: You're effectively using binary/bit flags. Look into bitwise operations.

Comment: *" I thought that saving the subjects and hours from a student in two separate strings would be the best way to store the information."* - I think that is a misconception. Make a table of subjects and a junction table that links students to subjects.

Comment: You lost me at: "And an average school day consists of 5 days"

Comment: Sorry, was supposed to be week, changed it @Torge

Comment: And I'll look into it @GolezTrol. Thanks

Comment: I guess it would be way easier for you to display the tutors after choosing the subject and only then choose the hours. **Subject -> Tutor -> Hours**

Comment: I know that I'd be easer @PedroLobito, but I want it to be as easy as possible for the student. It won't require searching for a best match. But thanks for your suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

Let's talk about bitstrings/bitwise operations in [PHP](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.bitwise.php) and [MySQL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/bit-functions.html).

A binary string is effectively exactly what you are describing. To simplify, let's pretend that there are only 4 classes:

```
$classes = 0b0101;
```

The student is taking classes 2 and 4

If you want to see if the user is taking a specific class, you can use a bitwise and:

```
if ($classes & 0b1000) {
    // user is in class 1
}
```

If you want to run a query to find all users in a class:

```
SELECT firstname FROM members WHERE subjects & 0b1000;
```

In these instances, you would store subjects as an integer, not as a string.

Now this says nothing about how it *should* be done (someone else mentioned junction tables, which is the correct answer), but you *could* use bitstrings and bitwise operations to achieve the implementation that you designed.

Comment: Thank you for suggesting a different approach, I do think that I'm gonna mess with junction table for a bit. Thanks anyways.